# What is the JVM script that I can use to stimulate DST(Day Light Saving Time)?

Tags: testing, jvm

I need to test data correctness after my database time changed due to DST and make sure that my system will not crash during DST.
I am looking for a JVM script to simulate this scenario.
Please let me know if you know about such script or other tools you familiar with for testing DST.

Comment: so you need to simulate that "today" is the day when time is modified for saving light?? is that correct?

Comment: You need to change the system clock to just before the daylight saving change and check everything is still working afterwards.  You can use the normal command line tools do do this using Runtime.exec